# Thymeleaf is not checking values when I load the list into a form

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a list of elements (where each element has an "id" and "name"), so the user will select from a checkbox list which of them they need, once the user selects the elements that he wants then I store the selected values in the DB (this is working).

When I try to load those values into another form (editing purposes) I need to load all the possible values and mark with a "check" those that the user selects during the creation.

I have the following code in my edit form, but I cannot get the selected values being checked by thymeleaf.  Could you please give an idea how to solve it?

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="checkboxes">Samples checkboxes</label>
        <div>
            <div class="btn-group btn-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label th:each="elem : ${elements}"
                    th:for="${#ids.next('objectName.selectedElements')}"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    th:classappend="${#lists.contains(objectName.selectedElements, elem)} ? 'active'">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        th:field="*{objectName.selectedElements}"
                        th:text="${elem.name}"
                        th:value="${elem.id}" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please ignore this question, the code above works perfectly.  The problem was at the selectedElements list that is was not loading the elements correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> try this, using `th:attr`

```
<input th:if="${filterType == 'Unapproved'}" type="checkbox" th:attr="name=${file.id}" th:value="Approved" th:text="Approve"/>
<input th:if="${filterType == 'Unapproved'}" type="checkbox"  th:attr="name=${file.id}" th:value="Deleted" th:text="Delete"/>
<input th:if="${filterType == 'Approved'}" type="checkbox" th:attr="name=${file.id}" th:value="Unapproved" th:text="Unapprove" />
<input th:if="${filterType == 'Deleted'}" type="checkbox" th:attr="name=${file.id}" th:value="Approved" th:text="Approve" />
```